# Understanding how to localize resources

Tags: c#, .net, resources, localization, embedded-resource

I know that there are lot of example but I didn't get my head around it... I just want to localize some strings and textfiles. That's what I currently do to receive a string or filecontent

```
MyResources.ResourceManager.GetString(name + "IdentString");
```

now I was looking for a way to store additional languages. The resources are wrapped into provider (about twelve provider at the moment, but that count will grow in the future) used by a ASP.Net MVC application (no view attached!)

As far as I know there are two ways to archive this:

- Satellite assembly for each language that contains the resource
- Filebased ResourceManager where each language has it's own binary resource file

And as far as I understand I have to use *external* tools in both scenarios and either have to link some satellite assemblies to the origin resource (each for one language) that get automatically loaded by the resource manager or I have to use a *FilebasedResourceManager* that loads the resource-file (a binary version for each language) from a external location. That means in both cases only the origin resource is embed in the project and the others are just *attached* in some sort. Did I get it right or am I totally wrong?

*Some additional info*

No need to say that I don't have any idea which one to take or how they really work or if there even other ways. As I started looking for this I thought about just naming my resource file after a convention like `fr-resource.resx` or `de-resource.resx` so that the resource-manager can take the thread culture or a given one and try to fetch the string from this resource or fallback to the default. But I found just something about satellites (what just remind me of a damn song) which should be registered to the `web.config` but need to build by just external tools...

Comment: I did translation by myself yet because it does not work like a charm in my situations. I made a class for languages. This class can iterate though all items. If item has the "|" in the title or text the class knows that text is allowed to translate. For me it is more easy than handling the locations of resources. But at Microsoft demonstration it looks very easy to work with. I hope someone will create a tutorial from the beginning to the end :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are on the right path by renaming the resx files according to culture. However you'd name them like the following

- `resources.resx` (This will be the default fallback.)
- `resources.de.resx` (This will be the culture neutral german resources.)

If you place these files next to the default resx and include them in the project then the compiler will take care of building the sattelite assemblies, and the resource manager will take care of finding them.

Sattelite assemlies will be blaced in a sub-folder with the name of the culture. So if you have `\myApp.exe` as the output you will also get a `\de\myApp.resources.dll`

You won't have to do something to link these files to your original assembly. If you "forget" to supply theses sattelite assembly's your app just won't have german resources and falls back to the default.

Comment: Peter I will give it a try. Thanks for the additional info! That was really what I am looking for.